# What are the steps used to generate the Erlangen map?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have imported a .osm file from QGIS and then I used sumo-0.22.0 to generate .net.xml ; .poly.xml and .rou.xml files since I use Veins-4a2. When I simulated the scenario of Veins, the application layer of RSU did not executed. So I need to understand how the Erlangen files was done because the problem is my scenario (my files). 
Can you tell me please what are the steps used to generated the .net.xml ; .poly.xml and .rou.xml?

Comment: If you're talking about those included with the VEINS distribution, as far as I'm aware the traffic in there was created by hand (I'm not sure about the map import, but it is rather old).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I mean what is the version of sumo used to generate erlangen.net.xml; erlangen.poly.xml and erlangen rou.xml? Or there files was created by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have a look at the xml files with a text editor or even a simple pager. Almost all sumo tools write a header to their output files which tells the version, the options and the date of creation. In case of the erlangen network this says:

```
<!-- generated on Wed Nov 30 12:18:33 2011 by SUMO netconvert Version 0.13.1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.sf.net/xsd/netconvertConfiguration.xsd">

    <input>
        <type-files value="erlangen.edgetypes.xml"/>
        <osm-files value="erlangen.osm"/>
    </input>

    <output>
        <output-file value="erlangen.net.xml"/>
    </output>

    <projection>
        <proj.utm value="true"/>
    </projection>

    <edge_removal>
        <remove-edges.isolated value="true"/>
    </edge_removal>

    <processing>
        <osm.discard-tls value="true"/>
        <no-turnarounds value="false"/>
        <offset.disable-normalization value="true"/>
        <roundabouts.guess value="true"/>
        <junctions.join value="true"/>
    </processing>

</configuration>
-->
```

which mentions all the information asked for (hopefully). The route file has no such header, so I suppose, it is handmade.

Comment: Thank you for your response.